# Wait for git command inside subprocess call to complete before submitting pull request

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, github-api

I'm trying to submit a pull request on a new branch that I created with pyGithub (https://github.com/jacquev6/PyGithub) API.  I'm getting varying results every time I run my script.  Sometimes I'm able to create the pull request at the end of the loop and sometimes it errors out saying that there is no difference in commits between my master branch and the new branch I've created.  I'm sure this is due to the "git push origin new_branch" command not finishing in time since it's being called in a subprocess.  How can I wait for the git call to finish before continuing?  I tried to use .wait() on my process, but I think that it will wait for the "subprocess" to finish, but not the git call, which is a separate command.  Any ideas how to do this?  Or perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way.  My code:

```
from github import Github
import getpass
import subprocess

username = input("Please enter your GitHub username: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
g = Github(username, password)

base_branch = input("Please enter your base branch, default --> [master]: ")
base_branch = base_branch or 'master'

new_branch = input("Please enter your new branch name: ")

authorName = input("Please enter the github organization name: ")
# author validation
try:
    author = g.get_organization(authorName)
except GithubException as ghe:
    print(ghe)

repos = input("Please enter a comma separated list of repo names: ").split(',')

# projects validation
if repos[0] == '':
    repos = input("No repos entered. \n Please enter a comma separated list of repos names: ").split(',')

for repo in repos:
    # retrieve info on the base_branch
    repoObj = author.get_repo(repo)
    baseBranch = repoObj.get_branch(base_branch)

    # create the new branch
    repoObj.create_git_ref('refs/heads/'+new_branch, baseBranch.commit.sha)

    # touch readme.md in the new branch and commit the change
    subprocess.call(['git', 'checkout', '-B', new_branch, 'origin/' + base_branch], cwd='./' + repo)
    subprocess.call("echo '' >> README.md", shell=True, cwd='./' + repo)
    subprocess.call(['git', 'commit', '-am "First Commit:"' + new_beanch + '"'], cwd='./' + repo)
    pushProcess = subprocess.call(['git', 'push', 'origin', new_branch], cwd='./' + repo)
    pushProcess.wait()

    newBranch = repoObj.get_branch(new_branch)
    # create pull request
    repoObj.create_pull(release_title, 'Main Release Ticket: ',baseBranch.commit.sha,newBranch.commit.sha)
```

Comment: I think i need to use the git ref edit function in order to update my reference with a new commit as part of the solution (http://jacquev6.github.io/PyGithub/github_objects/GitRef.html)

Comment: Looks like I may also have to use the subprocess module in order to do this, going to mess around with it